# Clase genérica Java

Tags: java

Muy buenas! Estoy aprendiendo a usar clases genéricas pero hay algo que no acabo de ver claro. El problema es el siguiente: Necesito un método que pasándole un objeto Producto, lo añada al carrito de la compra (cart) y dependiendo el tipo de producto que sea reste el stock o sume las ventas totales. Mi pregunta es, como diferencio qué tipo de producto me dan como parámetro sin hacer getClass() e instanciar el objeto? Clase padre Product, de la que heredan: DigitalProduct y PhysicalProduct, de este primera herendan Audiobook y Ebook y de la segunda Book, Movie y Magazine. Cada una con su variable stock y demás. Sin usar programación genérica lo he hecho así, pero se que con programas grandes no es eficiente y se hace difícil de leer. Alguien podría explicarme como implementar la programación genérica en un caso así? Muchas gracias! Disculpar si es mucho código.

```
   public boolean add(Product product) {
        if (product == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("[ERROR] Product object cannot be null");
        }

        if (product.getClass().getSimpleName() == "Audiobook") {
            Audiobook audiobook = (Audiobook) product;
            audiobook.incSales();
            audiobook.incSalesTotal();
            cart.add(audiobook);
            return true;
        }
        if (product.getClass().getSimpleName() == "Ebook") {
            Ebook ebook = (Ebook) product;
            ebook.incSales();
            ebook.incSalesTotal();
            cart.add(ebook);
            return true;
        }
        if (product.getClass().getSimpleName() == "Book") {
            Book book = (Book) product;
            if (book.getStock() > 0) {
                book.decStock();
                book.incSales();
                cart.add(book);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (product.getClass().getSimpleName() == "Magazine") {
            Magazine magazine = (Magazine) product;
            if (magazine.getStock() > 0) {
                magazine.decStock();
                magazine.incSales();
                cart.add(magazine);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            Movie movie = (Movie) product;
            if (movie.getStock() > 0) {
                movie.decStock();
                movie.incSales();
                cart.add(movie);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Muchas gracias! Un saludo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!